# How can I get the correct value from a dictionary with another list as keys?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

I tried my best to look for other answers, but I don't manage to find out how I can do it.

I have a dictionary like this:

```
namedict = {'0': 'female\tLotta\tAskildsen', '1': 'male\tHendrich\tDyb', '2': 'female\tRut\tAase', '3': 'male\tSigve\tBuer', '4': 'female\tBetina\tDimmen', '5': 'male\tOsvald\tAndvik', '6': 'female\tGunnbjørg\tAarset', '7': 'male\tMorten\tAlm', '8': 'female\tInes\tAbelsen', '9': 'male\tStian\tBerthelsen', '10': 'male\tGulbrand\tBrekka', '11': 'male\tHåvar\tClaussen', '12': 'female\tThi\tAslam', '13': 'female\tAslaug\tDuong', '14': 'female\tTora\tChristensen', '15': 'male\tLucas\tDrevland', '16': 'male\tOluf\tBirkedal', '17': 'male\tHalvar\tByberg', '18': 'male\tLeif\tBach', '19': 'female\tAyse\tBaltzersen', '20': 'female\tAnastasia\tBergli', '21': 'male\tRonald\tAasberg', '22': 'female\tElly\tDehli', '23': 'female\tElizabeth\tAalberg', '24': 'male\tRunar\tAsk'}
```

What I would like to do, is to use another list:

```
mylist = ['16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '15']
```

And get a new list with the names corresponding to the key:value in namedict.

Like this:

```
newlist = ['Oluf\tBirkedal', 'Halvar\tByberg', 'Leif\tBach', --->]
```

I tried to convert newlist to a tuple, but I don't understand how I use the tuple as keys in the dictionary.

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dict.get` with `list comprehesion` as:

```
newlist = [namedict.get(value).split('\t',1)[1] for value in mylist]

print(newlist)
['Oluf\tBirkedal',
 'Halvar\tByberg',
 'Leif\tBach',
 'Ayse\tBaltzersen',
 'Anastasia\tBergli',
 'Ronald\tAasberg',
 'Elly\tDehli',
 'Elizabeth\tAalberg',
 'Lucas\tDrevland']
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Below is also another approach of doing the same.

```
namedict = {'0': 'female\tLotta\tAskildsen', '1': 'male\tHendrich\tDyb', '2': 'female\tRut\tAase', '3': 'male\tSigve\tBuer', '4': 'female\tBetina\tDimmen', '5': 'male\tOsvald\tAndvik', '6': 'female\tGunnbjørg\tAarset', '7': 'male\tMorten\tAlm', '8': 'female\tInes\tAbelsen', '9': 'male\tStian\tBerthelsen', '10': 'male\tGulbrand\tBrekka', '11': 'male\tHåvar\tClaussen', '12': 'female\tThi\tAslam', '13': 'female\tAslaug\tDuong', '14': 'female\tTora\tChristensen', '15': 'male\tLucas\tDrevland', '16': 'male\tOluf\tBirkedal', '17': 'male\tHalvar\tByberg', '18': 'male\tLeif\tBach', '19': 'female\tAyse\tBaltzersen', '20': 'female\tAnastasia\tBergli', '21': 'male\tRonald\tAasberg', '22': 'female\tElly\tDehli', '23': 'female\tElizabeth\tAalberg', '24': 'male\tRunar\tAsk'}
mylist = ['16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '15']

new_list = [(namedict[i].split("\t")[1]+"\t"+namedict[i].split("\t")[2]) for i in mylist]
print(new_list)
```

Output:

```
['Oluf\tBirkedal', 'Halvar\tByberg', 'Leif\tBach', 'Ayse\tBaltzersen', 'Anastasia\tBergli', 'Ronald\tAasberg', 'Elly\tDehli', 'Elizabeth\tAalberg', 'Lucas\tDrevland']
```

Answer (score 0):

This will be more convenient if the values of `namedct` were themselves dicts, tuples or namedtuples.
Additionally, if your keys are consecutive numbers starting at zero, a list might be more appropriate, so something like this:

```
name_list = [
    ('male', 'Foo', 'Bar'),
    ('female', 'Spam', 'Baz'),
    # ...
]
```

Then you can extract the values of indices in `mylist` like so:

```
[name_list[i][1:] for i in mylist]
```

If you want to preserve the tab character:

```
['\t'.join(name_list[i][1:]) for i in mylist]
```